# Select <input> in a specific <td> element using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

How can I select an input within a `td`? Here is my `tr`:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="contact_email" placeholder="Email">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="contact_phone_num" placeholder="Phone #">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="contact_notes" placeholder="Notes">
    </td>
    <td>
        <button type="" class="btn btn-success add_contact">Add Contact</button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

My JavaScript:

```
var context = {
    first_name: $(this).closest('tr').find('input').eq(0).html(),
    last_name: $(this).closest('tr').find('input').eq(1).html(),
    contact_email: $(this).closest('tr').find('input').eq(2).html(),
    contact_phone_num: $(this).closest('tr').find('input').eq(3).html(),
    contact_notes: $(this).closest('tr').find('input').eq(4).html()
};
```

This returns empty when I log `context`.

Comment: `this` refers to ??????????

Comment: Just `closest('tr input').eq(INDEX)`

Comment: You need to use `val()` not `html()`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two problems in your code.

1. `<input>` elements don't have innerHTML, you can use [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to get the value of an input.
2. To select the nth `<td>` element, you need to use [`eq(index)`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) on the `td` element and not on the `<input>`.

Assuming `this` refers to the any element inside `<tr>`.

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('input').eq(0).html()
```

should be

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('td').eq(0).find('input').val()
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                    : Get the 0 index `td`
                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^      : select input inside it
                                                     ^^^^ : Get the value of input
```

Answer (score 0):

The inputs are not equivalent to use eq(0), eq(1), etc. because all inputs are the first-child elements inside the td elements.

You should be doing like this:

```
$(this).closest('td').eq(0).find('input').val();
$(this).closest('td').eq(1).find('input').val();
$(this).closest('td').eq(2) //first find nth element from td
  .find('input').val()//then find its input & get the value.
```

I am unsure if the `closeset('td')` would work or not because you didn't specified the the context of `this`. You may still use `$(this).closest('tr').find('td').eq(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.add_contact').click(function () {

            var context = {
                first_name: $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(0)').find('input').val(),
                last_name: $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(1)').find('input').val(),
                contact_email: $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(2)').find('input').val(),
                contact_phone_num: $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(3)').find('input').val(),
                contact_notes: $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(4)').find('input').val()
            };


        });
    });
</script>
</head>

<body>
   <table>
       <tbody>

           <tr>
    <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name" value="Chikku">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" value="Ferna">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="contact_email" placeholder="Email" value="chikku@gmail.com">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="contact_phone_num" placeholder="Phone #" value="2423424">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="contact_notes" placeholder="Notes" value="sample">
    </td>
    <td>
        <button type="" class="btn btn-success add_contact">Add Contact</button>
    </td>
</tr>



       </tbody>
   </table>

</html>
```